# String.format and gsub in Lua

Tags: string, lua, gsub, string.format, lua-patterns

```
function string:split(sep)    
 local sep, fields = sep or ":", {}   
local pattern = string.format("([^%s]+)", sep)    
 self:gsub(pattern,function (c)fields[#fields + 1] = c end)
 print(c)
return fields
   end
```

I have above block of code.

1. `string.format` function has separator as its second argument. Why is that? We generally have the blob of text as second argument which needs to be formatted.
2. `gsub` function usually replace a given pattern. what is he role of `function(c)` in `gsub`? How is it being called and used here? Where is `c` coming from in `function(c)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the example code, the format specifier of `string.format()` is `"([^%s]+)"`, in which `%s` expects a string, thus the second argument `sep` is a string.

   For instance, if `sep` has a value of `","`, then `pattern` becomes `([^,]+)` (one or more occurrences of non-commas), which means the function `string:split` is splitting strings by commas (`,`)
2. `string.gsub()` can take three types as the second argument, a string, a function, or a table. When it's a function, it is called every time a match occurs, with all captured substrings passed as arguments, in order. For more details, see [`string.gsub()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub).